# Eigen Values of Elemetary Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $n\times n$ elementary matrix $E = I - \alpha xy^T$, I want to show that $E$ must have at least $n-1$ eigenvalues equal to one, and finds an expression for other eigenvalues.

I assume $x \in null(y^T)$ so I have $y^Tx = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha xy^Tx =0 \Rightarrow x - \alpha xy^Tx = x \Rightarrow Ex = x $ now if I prove that $dim(null(y^T))$ is at least $n-1$ then the firt part is solved. I don't know how to prove this.

For the second part, is my below reasoning ok?
I suppose that $\alpha y^Tx = 1 \Rightarrow x - \alpha xy^Tx = 0 \Rightarrow Ex = 0$. So the other eigenvalue is zero.

Comment: In what sense is $E$ an "elementary matrix"?  Are $x$ and $y$ necessarily  columns of the identity matrix?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are any $n$-vectors .It is definition of elementary matrix or rank-one modification of identity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue: $y^T$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$ (or a $1 \times n$ matrix, if you prefer).  By the rank-nullity theorem (or "fundamental theorem of linear algebra"), the nullspace has dimension at least $n-1$, since the rank is at most $1$.

For your second issue: **if** $\alpha$ is such that $\alpha x^Ty = 1$, then the remaining eigenvalue is indeed $0$.  It's not clear, however, why you assume this condition holds.

In general, we may show that $x$ must be an eigenvector, since
$$
(I - \alpha xy^T)x = x - \alpha (y^Tx)x = [1 - \alpha y^Tx]x
$$
so in general, the remaining eigenvalue must be $1 - \alpha y^Tx$.  Another clever approach is to use the fact that the trace is the sum of all eigenvalues, and that $Tr(xy^T) = y^Tx$.